# Better way to perform multiple selects in one mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I've got an insert query that contains several select statements.  I feel like there's got to be a better (more efficient, more optimized, etc) way to do this.   Any suggestions?

```
   INSERT INTO log (logtype, subtype, src_ip, dst_ip, dst_port, query) VALUES (2, 1, 
    (SELECT src_ip FROM query WHERE uid="123"), 
    (SELECT dst_ip FROM query WHERE uid="123"), 
    (SELECT dst_port FROM query WHERE uid="123"), 
    (SELECT query FROM query WHERE uid="123"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO log (logtype, subtype, src_ip, dst_ip, dst_port, query) 
SELECT 2, 1, src_ip, dst_ip, dst_port, query 
FROM query WHERE uid="123"
```